# Using web worker with setTimeout or setInterval cause the memory leak

Tags: web-worker

I made a timer by setTimeout and web worker.
But I found that the browser's memory usage is getting higher as time go.

The digit here circled is getting bigger every 1 second just because my timer is looping every 1 second.
[image]

And the heap graph also indicate that the memory usage is increasing...
[image]

Here's my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-shannon-se0ysh

I don't know why the memory usage is increasing, can anyone help me with this problem? tks

I don't want the memory usage increases which may cause memory leak.

Comment: Code inside the question itself please. Since I'm in a good mood: In your tick handler, you never delete `timeoutIds[e.data.id]`, so your `timeoutIds` object keeps growing. Simply add `delete timeoutIds[e.data.id]` in the `setTimeout` handler (e.g before or after you `postMessage("timer:tick")`)

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you. But it is still increasing after I added `delete timeoutIds[e.data.id]` before or after `postMessage("timer:tick")`.

Comment: We still need to have the code in the question itself. And there might be somewhere else you don't clean correctly.